# zope.testrecorder on Plone 4.1

Tags: integration-testing, plone, zope

I want to install [zope.testrecorder](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.testrecorder) to create some functional tests for a Plone 4.1 package I'm writing.

I followed the instructions on both, package's INSTALL.txt file and Martin Aspeli's tutorial [Using zope.testrecorder to record functional tests](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/testing/zope-testrecorder), but they seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://davidjb.com/blog/2010/03/plonezope-utilising-zope-testrecorder-for-unit-testing

There he says:

"""
Go to http://zopehost:port/++resource++recorder/index.html to access the test recorder, and not try and add an object in the root of Zope (or elsewhere).
"""

Also make sure to install the zope.testrecorder as an egg and zcml (there's no autoinclude ATM) in in your buildout -- instead of unzipping the tarball inside the products/ directory as Aspeli suggested in his a bit outdated tutorial.